# Insert Reusable Content Button in MOSS 2010

Tags: reusable

I am starting with Sharepoint and I am trying to use the "Reusable Content" feature.

I have added the new reusable content item to the list, but I can't find the "Insert Reusable Content" button on the editor ribbon.

Do I need to activate any option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the SharePoint Server Publishing Features at the Site Collection level, and then also at the Site level. Enabling these features adds the option in the Ribbon.

Site Collection Feature:
SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure 
Provides centralized libraries, content types, master pages and page layouts and enables page scheduling and other publishing functionality for a site collection

Site Feature: 
SharePoint Server Publishing 
Create a Web page library as well as supporting libraries to create and publish pages based on page layouts. 
Dependencies: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (Site Collection)

SharePoint 2010 | Content Publishing

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Reusable Content list it sounds like you have the necessary features activated. To insert one of your reusable content items you can navigate to a page and in edit mode, in a suitable area of the page (i.e. a text field) you can use the Reusable Content button in the *Editing Tools | Insert* tab on the ribbon.

Thanks